# Sending xml layout to an Android activity using intents

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

1)Is it possible to use the intents mechanism on Android to send some activity a URI of a .xml file and have that activity use that xml file as its view layout ?

2)Specifically, I want to make a generic level chooser for games. So I want it to be able to have as much flexibility as possible when it comes to its looks. And still retain a listview-like functionality (be able to return the number of level chosen by the user to the calling activity). Would sending an xml file as layout work for that purpose ? If not, how would you do it ?

Comment: I think u should try Layout Fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the id number of the layout, and on then just `setContentView(layoutId);` with the received value.

Comment: This does not acomplish what I need. I want to be able to write an xml layout -after- my level chooser activity has been compiled and uploaded to a device. And send it as part of an intent from an altogether different app. My question was if that kind of operation is even possible.

Comment: it can't be done. The XML layout is pre-processed by the SDK compiler on your PC before packaging the .apk. Inside the .apk itself there's no XML. You would have to create your own parcelable that describes a level and a tool to generate the level on during runtime.